# Web statistic tracking and RSS

Tags: google-analytics, web-statistics

With RSS feeds how do you set up google analytics (or any other statistical tracker) to track people who are subscribed to the feed?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It looks like you have two options. Use [FeedBurner](http://www.feedburner.com/fb/a/home) (owned by Google) for your feed which will provide you with lots of stats (even more than you may want) or you can use the method found here: http://www.gospelrhys.co.uk/2007/09/how-to-track-new-rss-subscribers-google-analytics-in-3-easy-steps.html to create a forwarding page which captures the click in Analytics, then forwards the user to your feed. It's is a little bit of a hassle, but if you have to use Analytics that seems to be the way to do it.